# is :where meant to collapse repeated selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given this html and this css:

```html
<div id="outer">
  <p>text the first</p>
  <div id="inner">
    <p>text the second</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
div :where(div p, .whatever) { color: red; }
```

.. then according to https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#zero-matches that css would be equivalent¹ to ..

```css
div div p, div .whatever { color: red; }
```

.. and so only "text the second" should be red.

*However* .. both paragraphs are styled as red², as if the css is actually just `div p, div .whatever { color: red; }`.

Every article I've read on `:where` and `:is` does not mention this behaviour.

**What's going on?** ³

---

¹ only with lower specificity, of course.
² in Chrome Version 92.0.4515.131 (MacOS), other browsers not tested.
³ it is way past my bedtime, maybe I've forgotten how to read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div :where(div p)` isn’t equivalent to `div div p`. In general, there’s no way to expand a selector that uses `:is`/`:where` to an equivalent single selector that doesn’t, but `div :where(div p)` specifically is exactly equivalent to `div p` as far as which elements it matches.

- `:where(div p)` matches elements that match `div p`
- `div :where(div p)` matches descendants of a `div` that match `div p`
- “descendants of a `div` that match `div p`” is “**descendants of a `div` that are descendants of a `div`** that match `p`”
- the bold part above is redundant

Comment: why always posting as "community"? :)

Comment: OK, that kinda makes sense — the `:where()` or `:is()` isn't acting similar to a pre-processor and being expanded *syntacically* inline behind the scenes (which many articles heavily imply), but is instead being tested *semantically*? The right mental model is needed for interpretation.

Comment: Is there any point to writing `div :where(div p)` and not simply `:where(div p)` ?

Comment: @Erics: Being expanded or not is an implementation detail; for understanding the concept, the semantics are what matters. No, there’s no good point to writing `div :where(div p)` instead of `:where(div p)` – they only differ in specificity. But if that’s the entire selector you should just write `div p`.

Comment: @Erics: The vast majority of articles that explain it that way fail to account for edge cases such as this.